# Change labelwidth for multienumerate (multienum)

Tags: lists

I am trying to increase the `\labelwidth` from 18pt to 22pt for a multienumerate. However, the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multienumerate}\setlength{\labelwidth}{22pt}
\mitemxxx
{$T(0,0)$}
{$A(-11,0)$}
{$A(3,50)$}
\end{multienumerate}        
\end{document}
```

will shift everything to the right (instead of squeezing) and the last item is pushed to a new line. I have tried to decrease `\usedx` and `\remainx` but I was not able to find a solution such that everything is still on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `multienum` package doesn't allow to customize lenghts, but I think you can reach what you want with the more flexible package `tasks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    style=enumerate,
    label-width={22pt},
    item-indent={22pt+.3333em},
    label-align=right,
%   debug=true % useful for fine-tuning or debugging
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tasks}(3)
     \task $T(0,0)$
     \task $A(-11,0)$
     \task $A(3,50)$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After reading the documentation of the tasks package, I would consider tasks as a generalization of multienum (i.e. everything that is possible with multienum is possible with tasks, too).

Comment: @LinusRomer I think `tasks` is a spin-off of `ExSheets`, probably they have different origins but, eventually, do the same things. BTW, thank you for accepting my answer.